# Create record with id

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I need to import the data from a different database and transfer it to the new database. but the ID information of the members is required for the relationship. I have to carry them too.
Therefore, I have to fill in the ID column which is increased as AUTOINCREMENT.

My Migrate Controller

```
 public function migrate(BackupUser $buser, User $user)
            {
                $backup_user = $buser->get();

                foreach ($backup_user as $bulk) {
                    $user->create([
                        'id'         => $bulk->uye_id,
                        'name'       => $bulk->uye_nick,
                        'email'      => $bulk->uye_mail,
                        'password'   => $bulk->uye_sifre,
                        'created_at' => $bulk->uye_tarih
                    ]);
                }
            }
```

when I do this, the AUTOINCREMENT increases normally and I can not get the ID information of the previous members.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Where is the code for relations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `id` field for `User` is not fillable by mass assignment like you're doing. If you want to assign it, you must add `'id'` to the array of fillable fields in the user class.

app/User.php

```
...
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
...
```

Comment: Create is not good idea to take database from others tables. How you will related then, with same iday probably work. But it never find if there is any relation mistake in previous table. How would you filter garbage data ?

Comment: This is an answer to the question posted of why the auto-increment increases normally and the ID doesn't match what it is set to in the `create()` call. You're right in that there is probably a better way to migrate the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to take database from joomla or wordpress to laravel.

If I need to do this . my approach would be to store first all base tables without `id` and then with stored id generated after insertion would be in related tables. So the steps would be

```
  S1:  store new `user` and get `id`
  S2:  relate with other table like `role` with `user_id`
  Loop again till last row
```